# Coldfusion per application mapping randomly fails

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-2018

In my application.cfc file I have the following code:

```
this.mappings["/includes"] = "#expandPath('../../priv/inc/')#";
```

and then on a page I have the following CF include set up:

```
<cfinclude template="/includes/imageOptimise-thumbnail.cfm">
```

For the majority of the time when the page is submitted the imageOptimise-thumbnail page runs without any issue but occasionally it will error saying that it can't find the imageOptimise-thumbnail.cfm. If I resubmit the page, chances are it will work but the question is, why is it sometimes not being able to find the page?

I had a look in the CF Admin and I can't see anything in the logs saying that there was an error but it is clearly showing a Coldfusion 'template not found' error message when it fails.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I think your issues stem from the fact that the path used for the mapping is relative.

According to advice in [ColdFusion Mappings and Relative Paths](https://www.elliottsprehn.com/blog/2010/02/19/coldfusion-mappings-and-relative-paths/),

> the moral of the story is to NEVER use expandPath() to create a
>   mapping that’s relative to the webroot.

Try to make the webroot static as the blog suggests

```
<cfset this.mappings["/myapplication"] =getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())
```

and navigate to `/priv/inc/` from the webroot

Comment: i think i understand but how would i write the correct mapping using your example to point to the priv/inc folder?

Comment: Try something like this.... `<cfset webroot= GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())>   <cfset this.mappings["/includes"]  = "#webroot#/path/to/priv/inc/" />`